# Alternative for hashing Files to recognize them?

Tags: hash

I´m searching a way to recognise files depending on their content. So I need a method which is independent of the files location, name, attributes and so on.

Normally I would use a hash function like SHA-1 or MD5. The problem is the size of the files I want to identify. The files are usually between 5 - 15 GB.

My approach with SHA-1 hashes is not a good solution. Hashing such big files takes several minutes... I need something much faster which makes it possible to identify a file scanned previously in some seconds.

Is there another way than hashing files for such a demand?

My current Java code is comparable to `openssl sha1 <path>` on my Mac:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getPath());
    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

    int nread = 0; 

    while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
      md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
    };

    fis.close();
    byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();

    //convert the byte to hex format
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    return sb.toString();
```

But actually I´m looking for something other than such hashing algorithms. Do you have a idea? :-)

BR
m4xy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what kind of files you are dealing with, it might suffice to use only parts of the file for the hash. E.g. if this is compressed image data, chances are very very high, that you will get unique different hashes for your files if you only hash the first few kilobytes (and maybe the last few kilobytes). 
This might not work for uncompressed database dumps that always start identical.

Comment: I like the idea of hashing small parts of the file as a "good enough" solution. I will store that one away for future use.

Answer (score 0):

As a first early-out pass, you can simply compare file sizes.

Once you've hashed a file, you can store the hash with the file's ctime. As long as the ctime hasn't changed, there's no need to rehash. (You could use mtime instead, but you'd need to rely on the programs which modify the files not manually setting mtime to what it was.)